# WCF Service (Local System Account) detecting users proxy settings

Tags: .net, wcf, proxy

I'm struggling with an issue that, on the face of it, is well documented but I can't seem to crack.

My application is based around 2 components: a WCF Windows Service and a .net client forms application. The service runs all the time under the Local System account and is primarily used to check for updates, act as a pass-through for web-service calls and manage product information files.

Anyway, when the application is deployed to a user that accesses the web via a proxy the service fails to hit the web-services. This is expected, as the Local System account cannot detect the users proxy settings. I can't figure out how to get around this problem. I can easily solve it on a case by case basis by setting the defualtProxy information in the WCF service config file, but I can't manage the situation on a case-by-case basis - I need my service to detect the proxy settings at runtime. I've read about proxycfg and netsh but I can't see how I can use them in my service.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want, but I haven't been able to verify with many different proxy servers:

```
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
    <proxy usesystemdefault="True"/>
</defaultProxy>
```

Here's my related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307110/what-is-the-best-way-to-configure-proxy-related-settings-for-a-wcf-client) (not yet answered as of this writing)